# How can I simulate a listview inside a scrollview?

Tags: android, listview

I need to display user comments and replies to those comments in a hierarchical type of way where the child comment has a slight padding to the left.

I am able to do this with a listview view. but the listview is inside a scroll view and they don't work properly for obvious reasons.

I need to simulate a listview with a scrollview scrollview. How can I do this?

Comment: you should  not put listview under scroll view. but you can add header and footer to your listview.

Comment: give fix height to listview

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the docs

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

You inflate your views add it to the listview as a header and footer.

Have a custom view and add it as a footer

`public void addFooterView (View v)`

Added in API level 1

> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView
>   is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
>   added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.

NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.

> Parameters v  The view to add.

Make sure your listview is not empty otherwise you won't see the footer.